# Monitor a celery task state without polling?

Tags: python, celery

Is it possible to monitor the state of a celery task without polling?

For example, if I have a task which periodically updates its state using `update_state`:

```
@task(bind=True)
def my_task(self):
    for x in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'x': x})
```

Is it possible to monitor that state from another process without polling?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this myself yet, so this isn't a complete answer, but I have interest in solving the same problem.  I've got three ideas worth consideration:

- Would using the built-in [handler states](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#handlers) like `on_failure`, `on_retry`, and `on_success` work for your use case?
- Another is to subclass `Task` (trivial example here: [Callback for celery apply_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526606/callback-for-celery-apply-async)) and add `on_*` handlers that get passed callback functions for your custom states.  Perhaps that wouldn't even be necessary
- The best might be to [write a custom event receiver](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=receiver#real-time-processing).  I think this is how their ["Real-time Celery web-monitor"](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=receiver#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor) example works.  A related SO post on this is: [Implementing Twisted style local multiple deferred callbacks in Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475539/implementing-twisted-style-local-multiple-deferred-callbacks-in-celery/20533931#20533931).

Answer (score 2):

The [`on_message`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#on-message) callback allows you to specify a function that is called whenever a task changes state.

For example, the following task sends a custom `PROGRESS` state when it is called.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery("tasks", broker="pyamqp://guest@localhost//", backend="rpc://")

@app.task(bind=True)
def square(self, x):
    self.update_state(state="PROGRESS")
    return x**2
```

You can see this is the caller like so.

```
>>> tasks.square.delay(5).get(on_message=print)
{'task_id': 'f63eb965-3cdc-4bcc-a5e1-b0bb2149c376', 'status': 'PROGRESS', 'result': None, 'traceback': None, 'children': []}
{'task_id': 'f63eb965-3cdc-4bcc-a5e1-b0bb2149c376', 'status': 'SUCCESS', 'result': 25, 'traceback': None, 'children': []}
25
```

If you want a more involved example, I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/wpm/bfeba03746bd494092266a0691455b4a) that uses Celery to do a parallel copy of a directory of files while updating a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

It'll depend on your broker / backend. If they use pub/sub, then your process won't need to poll the task state. If they don't then you'll need to poll (or more generally a process that involves sending a message asking for state).

I think both celery and redis have that capability.

Comment: "process won't need to poll the task state" — but how will it access the task state?

Comment: But how specifically do you do that? Does Celery expose an API?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to track progress in your producer you will need to use the event monitoring API for this. The other apis, handlers and signals, only run in the worker; so no use for tracking progress in the producer.

Look at the section called "Monitoring and Management Guide" in the docs and you should be able to run the example code (for an events receiver) almost verbatim. It doesn't mention, however, event generation needs to be enabled for the worker too. The -E argument to your work will fix that.